# Listbox functionality, with RichText Formatting

Tags: c#, listbox, background-color, ownerdrawn

I'm working on an application that displays a report for e-mails that come into an outlook mailbox. I had set it up with a rich textbox to format the fore-color or back-color of the text according to the e-mail type. I wanted to add functionality for users to select an e-mail from the display.

Simple enough use a listbox...but keep the formatting... make it an owner-drawn-fixed listBox.

most of the time this works fine; until the user tries to select the e-mail.

here is what happens

On Double click:

1. get selected item and cast to info for pulling the outlook.mailItem
2. clear the selected items from the list
3. do whatever to the mail item (passed off to another function where
   the user chooses what he/she wants to do)
4. Calls update

update

1. clear the items in the listbox
2. pull the e-mails and add them back into the listBox

Somewhere in the update, the application locks up and I'm not sure why. When called as part of the "normal" application process, the report loads just fine, it only locks up, when called after a user interaction.

75% of the time, none of the error handlers I have, `Catch (exception e2)` get called. However, occasionally I'll get and index error throwing a value of -1.

Logically, if there it works in one case, it should work in the second, but evidence shows this to not be the case.

Any suggestions for where to look for the error, or a different route to explore to achieve the same goal?

```
        private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        SolidBrush textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        try
        {
            ListBox box = (ListBox)sender;
            mailInfo email = (mailInfo)box.Items[e.Index];
            switch (email.getTypeCode())//based on the e-mail type formats the line
            {
                case 1:// ejected
                    textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
                    backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    break;
                case 2://Multi volume
                    textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.SteelBlue);
                    backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    break;
                case 0://success
                    textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen);
                    backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    break;
                case -3://not inserted
                    textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.LightSalmon);
                    backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    break;
                case -2:// not scratch
                case -1:// fail
                case -4:// write portected
                case -5:// not in DB
                    textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                    break;
                default:
                    textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e2) { MessageBox.Show(e2.Message + "\n\ncode\n" + e2.StackTrace, e2.GetType().ToString()); }
        g.FillRectangle(backColor, e.Bounds);
        if(e.State == DrawItemState.Selected) {
            g.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, SystemBrushes.MenuHighlight,new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)); }
        else {
            g.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, textColor, new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        }
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    }


    private void lstEmail_DoubleClick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mailInfo email = (mailInfo) lstEmail.SelectedItem;
        lstEmail.ClearSelected();
        frmEmailSelectedOptions userAction = new frmEmailSelectedOptions();
        userAction.ShowDialog(this);
        switch (userAction.value)
        {
            case 0://ignore
                // allow function to close, no action neededd
                break;
            case 1://read/unread
            case 2://open
                data.performEmailAction(email,userAction.value);
                MessageBox.Show(userAction.value.ToString());
                break;
            case 3://filter
                this.filter = new mailFilter(email.getHost().getName(), email.getJobName());
                updateEmailList();
                break;
        }
    }public void updateEmailList()/***/
    {
        lstEmail.Items.Clear();
        txtFilter.Text = filter.ToString();// updates the fileter display to the current filter
        List<mailInfo> emails = data.getMail();// pulls the e-mails from the application memory
        if (!btnSortByTime.Checked)//checks if the data needs to be re-sorted
        {
            emails.Sort((x, y) => x.getHost().getOrder().CompareTo(y.getHost().getOrder()));
        }
        foreach (mailInfo email in emails)//iterates over each e-mail in the application memory
        {
            if (displayEmail(email))//checks if the e-mails passes all the criteria
            {

                lstEmail.Items.Add(email);//adds the e-mail to the list, plus a line return for the next e-mail.
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: what's the exception, do you actually get the exception from `box.Items[e.Index];`?

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

at System.Windows.FormsListBox.ObjectCollection.get_Item(int32 index)
at [...]frmMain.listbox_DrawItem(object sender, drawItemEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by checking if the listbox had focus. If the listbox has focus, I selected another control. If not leave the focus as is. This resolved the issue.